# Import of external Angular 2 component fails

Tags: angular, slider, webpack, angular2-components

I am using the ASP.NET Core Template which is using Webpack (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/31a3eab5-e62b-4030-9226-b5e4c9e1ffb5).

I am trying to import a bunch of external modules to my Angular 2 project. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-slider-component is one of them.

When opening the "ng2-slider-component" in my node_modules folder, I see the following files:

- ng2-slider.component.d.ts
- ng2-slider.component.html
- ng2-slider.component.js
- ng2-slider.component.js.map
- ng2-slider.component.system.js

I am missing something like "ng2-slider.component.ts" which I can import in my "app.module.ts". So I am trying to do this as shown below.

```
import { Ng2SliderComponent } from 'ng2-slider-component/ng2-slider.component';
```

and then use it in my @NgModule.

```
@NgModule({
bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
declarations: [
    Ng2SliderComponent
]})
```

But this throws an Internal Server Error: Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: moduleId should be a string in "Ng2SliderComponent". See  for more information.
If you're using Webpack you should inline the template and the styles.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add following piece of code to **`systemjs.config.js`**(If you are using system loader),

```
packages: {

    ....

    'node_modules/ng2-slider-component': {
            main: 'ng2-slider.component.system.js',
            defaultExtension: 'system.js' 
    },

    .... 

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I am using the ASP.NET Core Template (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/31a3eab5-e62b-4030-9226-b5e4c9e1ffb5). I canot see the systemjs.config.js file.